Idiom request - Just like a garland in monkey's hands
I'm seeking the English equivalent of the popular Tamil/South Indian saying
"Just like a garland in a monkey's hands.".
A monkey does not know what to do with a garland.
This adage is frequently used in a humorous manner when a simpleton marries a smart and intelligent girl.
Is there an English proverb that describes scenarios in which something valuable is offered to someone who does not recognise its worth?

Pearls before swine?

I was going to say "like a monkey with a smartphone".  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LVEgAMzvfI

See also When one has a spouse that they do not deserve him / her and Is there an English equivalent for the expression "Playing the flute to a buffalo"?

Like a fine wine in a dirty glass.

I don't think there is a widely used comparable idiom in English. In a comment, I had suggested "like a fine wine in a dirty glass," but that doesn't really capture it.
I might make up my own and say that it's "like giving a Rolls Royce to a child," or something similar. The child wouldn't appreciate the value and couldn't even drive the car.
